# Integrating with regard to a function of a measure ? (Change of measure)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ be a measure space. We define two measures on that space: $\mu$ and $\nu$ (they can be $\sigma$-finite if it helps). It happens that we can express $\mu$ in terms of $\nu$: $\mu = g(\nu)$. For example $\mu= \nu^2$ (can be anything, as long as $g(\nu)$ is a measure).

We only know how to integrate with regard to $\nu$ : $\int_A f(x) d\nu(x)$ is nicely computable. But we have an integral with regard to $\mu$ : $\int_A f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_A f(x) dg(\nu(x))$

Is there a way to change measure from $g(\nu)$ to $\nu$ by modifying the integrand and the domain of integration ?

We can assume that $g(0)=0$ if you think the solution is lying in the Radon-Nikodym theorem (so we need domination of measures).

Comment: Basically, to define integrals it suffices to understand how the measure behaves on measurable characteristic functions. The rest follows by approximation by simple functions. So the question is: what happens when you integrate against $\mu$ something like $\chi_A$, where $A$ is a measurable set, and $\chi_A(x)=1$ for all $x\in A$ and zero otherwise? And moreover, make sure that $g(\nu)$ is still a measure.

Comment: How is $\nu^2$ a measure???

Comment: For example, when $\nu$ is a probability measure and $\mathcal A$ is just $\Omega$ and the void.

Comment: @W.Volante Well, you see that this is a very trivial example, right? In fact, if $\nu^2$ is a measure, then the only set $A$ such that $\nu(A)\neq 0$ is $A = \Omega$. Moreover, if $g(\nu)$ is a measure and $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then $g$ is additive, i.e., $g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)$.